# Get the next instance of a specified date/time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

How do I use JavaScript (inc JQuery) to get a Date object that represents the next instance of 11:00?

My example is that if the current time is 15:00 on a Monday 2nd June, I'd want to return 11:00 Tuesday 3rd June. Likewise if the current date is 9:15 Thursday 5th June, I'd want to return 11:00 Thursday 5th June. So it should return the next instance of 11:00 based on the current date/time.

This is for a countdown to shipping cut-off (which is 11:00 each week day) on an ecommerce site.

Long term I'd like to also exclude weekends, for example if the current date is 09:00 on Saturday 7th June, it would return 11:00 Monday 9th June, but that is not my primary question for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
today=new Date()
b=new Date()
b.setHours(11) //11:00 AM, use 23 for 11:00 PM
b.setMinutes(0);
b.setSeconds(0);
if(today-b>0){
  b.setDate(b.getDate()+1)//if you're at the end of the week, it will adjust for you
}
//The following part kicks out weekends:
if(b.getDay()==0||){
  b.setDate(b.getDate()+1) //Sunday becomes Monday
}
if(b.getDay()==6){
  b.setDate(b.getDate()+2) //Saturday becomes Monday
}
console.log(b)
```

Simply set the hour to 11, compare with today, and add a day if it's already happened.

Comment: Hi, thanks. This works but only to the nearest hour. I need the nearest second. The approach by @d'alar'cop above seems to do the job. Just need some help on excluding weekends.

Comment: @MartinKearn: Added a bit about weekends, I'll fix the seconds as well.

Comment: Awesome - this seems to work perfectly, thanks very much. Both you and @d'alar'cop have answered the full question in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
var x = new Date();
var y = new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), (x.getHours()<11?(x.getDay()==0?x.getDate()+1:(x.getDay==6?x.getDate()+2:x.getDate())):x.getDate()+1), 11, 0, 0, 0);
console.log(y);
```

Cheers.

Comment: Not necessarily. This won't work if it is 1 AM, it will give 11AM _tomorrow_ though the next instance is 11AM _today_

Comment: @Manishearth Very kind of you to down vote. I think I may have fixed it. See edited version.

Comment: Hi, this is close but not quite (just tried it). It does return the time for tomorrow, not today. For example if I run this at 10:30, it will return tomorrow's 11:00, not the one in 30 minutes time.

Comment: Are you sure?? it really shouldn't do that - did you try the latest version?

Comment: Yes, the updated code does work - thanks! :) .... any clues on how to exclude weekends?

Comment: Yes - just gimme a sec! And tick that answer button there for motivation

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I guess I'll need to wait until Friday to fully test it but it looks like it will work just fine. Thanks for your help

Comment: you reversed my answer... not nice at all man (perhaps you had not realised that only _one_ answer can be ticked)

Comment: hey @d'alar'cop, I am really sorry about that - I did not realise I could only have 1 answer. It is daft really because both approaches work and both are valid answers. Either way, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I see. well fair enough buddy - it is daft in some cases! it's up to you anyway I guess - which one you are actually going to use?

Comment: holy lord this is so unmaintainable.